# Can I inspect the contents of an npm package before publish?

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like to be able to run a script on the contents of a npm package before it gets published to see if all the required files are presents. We recently had some published packages that were missing things as they had wrongfully been matched by patterns in `.npmignore`.

Is this possible? Will `npm install . -g` essentially do this by placing *the exact same contents* in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mypackage` as on `NPM`?

Comment: You could also use [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) to create a `.tgz` bundle of the package and then process is in any way you want.

Comment: aha, I knew there was something like that, just couldn't see the right command when doing `npm help`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`npm pack --dry-run` will output the to-be-published files to stderr, without doing any changes to the filesystem.

```
npm notice   @some/package@0.2.38
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 641B  package.json      
npm notice 961B  src/index.js      
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          @some/package                        
npm notice version:       0.2.38                                  
npm notice filename:      some-package-0.2.38.tgz              
npm notice package size:  1 kB                                  
npm notice unpacked size: 1.5 kB                                 
npm notice shasum:        somesha
npm notice integrity:     someothersha
npm notice total files:   2
```

You could assert on that list of files with a file that doesn't exist, e.g.

```
> npm pack --dry-run 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep src/someFileNotInPackage.js
> echo $?
1
```

Notice the 1, an error exit code.

Or on a file that does exist:

```
> npm pack --dry-run 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep src/index.js
> echo $?
0
```

Notice the 0, success exit code.

Comment: moving the accepted answer to this (from my own), since this requires no deps other than npm.

Answer (score 2):

This scripts checks for the files you pass in as params:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Checks to see if the published NPM package has the files passed in as arguments
# Requirements: jq and npm
# `brew install jq` on macOS and `apt install jq` on Ubuntu

pkg=$(echo $(jq .name package.json)-$(jq .version package.json).tgz | sed 's/"//g')
files_to_check="$@"

main(){
    npm pack > /dev/null 2>&1;
    check_tarball_files $@
    rm $pkg > /dev/null;
}

usage(){
    cat << EOF
Usage: check-files-present [file1 [file2 [...]]]

Example. Want to see that 'lolex' contains two specific files:
  check-files-present src/lolex-src.js package/lolex.js
EOF
    exit 1
}

if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then
    echo No file names given on command line
    usage
fi

check_tarball_files(){
    tarball_files=$(tar tf $pkg)
    for f in $files_to_check; do
        if !(echo $tarball_files | grep package/$f) > /dev/null; then
            echo "Missing $f" && exit 1
        fi
     done
     echo All files present: $files_to_check
}

main
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/6d12d2afd0a2236daea712f7216d538f)

Answer (score 0):

I run `npm pack && tar -xvzf *.tgz | cut -c9- && rm -rf package *.tgz` with Git Bash on Windows to list all files to be included in the published package.

For example, running the script on the [axios repository](https://github.com/axios/axios):

```sh
git clone https://github.com/axios/axios.git
cd axios
npm install
npm run build
```

Pack, extract the archive, trim `package/` prefix and cleanup afterward:

```sh
npm pack && tar -xvzf *.tgz | cut -c9- && rm -rf package *.tgz
```

This results in a list of files included in the package to be deployed:

```sh
axios-0.19.0.tgz
LICENSE
dist/axios.js
lib/axios.js
lib/core/Axios.js
dist/axios.min.js
lib/helpers/bind.js
lib/core/buildFullPath.js
lib/helpers/buildURL.js
lib/cancel/Cancel.js
lib/cancel/CancelToken.js
lib/helpers/combineURLs.js
lib/helpers/cookies.js
lib/core/createError.js
lib/defaults.js
lib/helpers/deprecatedMethod.js
lib/core/dispatchRequest.js
lib/core/enhanceError.js
lib/adapters/http.js
index.js
lib/core/InterceptorManager.js
lib/helpers/isAbsoluteURL.js
lib/cancel/isCancel.js
lib/helpers/isURLSameOrigin.js
lib/helpers/isValidXss.js
lib/core/mergeConfig.js
lib/helpers/normalizeHeaderName.js
lib/helpers/parseHeaders.js
lib/core/settle.js
lib/helpers/spread.js
lib/core/transformData.js
lib/utils.js
lib/adapters/xhr.js
package.json
dist/axios.map
dist/axios.min.map
CHANGELOG.md
lib/adapters/README.md
lib/core/README.md
lib/helpers/README.md
README.md
UPGRADE_GUIDE.md
index.d.ts
```

The first line should be skipped as it is the name of the archive (package and version).

Comment: If you just use tf instead of xf you list the contents instead of extracting them. Basically the script I posted, in other words :)